# Hololens: how to adjust cursor pointer sensibility

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I am developing an MR application using unity and MRTK library. Is it possible to modify Hololens cursor pointer sensibility. If yes, how to do so? Do I have to do it in Unity or is there an option in Windows environment ?

Comment: Adjusting the pointer sensitivity is an infrequent requirement. Could you provide more information about your business requirements? What trouble does the current configuration cause for your APP?

Comment: I'm developping an AR measurement application and because the pointer is very sensible, our measures aren't always as precise as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description,  I think your needs are to make the app more precise targeting. You can try modifying the `StoredStabilitySamples` property of the [GazeStabilizer](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Physics.GazeStabilizer.html) object to do this.  It iterates over samples of Raycast data and helps stabilize the user's gaze for precision targeting.

If you have [added MRTKv2 to your scene](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTheMRTK.html#add-mrtk-to-a-new-scene-or-new-project),  you will see MixedRealityToolkit and MixedRealityPlayspace in your Scene hierarchy. You can refer to the following steps to modify this property:

In your UnityEditor, select [MixedRealityPlayspace] -> [Camera] object in the Hierarchy window, then find the [Gaze Provider] component in the Inspector window and change [Stored Stability Samples] property to a suitable value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working now. The application is a lot more comfortable to use.